# xsl:apply-templates not iterating over each node given by select

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I'm using Saxon HE 9-4-0-3J. My intent is to use the `select` attribute on `xsl:apply-templates` to iterate over each `<RECORD>` element, but only a single `<RECORD>` element in the xml is being processed.

**xml**

```
<ENVELOPE>
<PRODUCT>
    <HEAD><FLAG>No</FLAG></HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <RECORD><Value>9</Value></RECORD>
        <RECORD><Value>10</Value></RECORD>
        <MISC>9</MISC>
    </BODY>
</PRODUCT>
```

**xslt 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/ENVELOPE">
<Interface>
   <Data><xsl:apply-templates select="PRODUCT"/></Data>
</Interface>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="PRODUCT">
   <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="HEAD/FLAG='Yes'">
         <xsl:attribute name="Match">Affirmative</xsl:attribute>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="BODY/RECORD" mode="affr"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="HEAD/FLAG='No'">
         <xsl:attribute name="Match">Negative</xsl:attribute>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="BODY/RECORD" mode="neg"/>
      </xsl:when>
   </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="RECORD" mode="affr">
   <xsl:attribute name="Value"><xsl:value-of select="Value"/></xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="RECORD" mode="neg">
   <xsl:attribute name="Value"><xsl:value-of select="Value"/></xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<Interface>
      <Data Match="Negative" Value="9"/> <!-- this line doesn't appear, I want it to -->
      <Data Match="Negative" Value="10"/>
</Interface>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<DATA...>` output tag is generated when you match `<ENVELOPE...>`, so there can only be one of these output.  Any `<xsl:attribute>` directives merely add to this output tag, with later values overwriting earlier ones.

You must explicitly generate the `DATA` tags you want output, as in:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/ENVELOPE">
    <Interface>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="PRODUCT"/>
    </Interface>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="PRODUCT">
    <xsl:variable name="flag">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="HEAD/FLAG='Yes'">Affirmative</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="HEAD/FLAG='No'">Negative</xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="BODY/RECORD">
      <xsl:with-param name="flag"><xsl:value-of select="$flag"/></xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:apply-templates>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="RECORD">
    <xsl:param name="flag"/>
    <Data Value="{Value}" Match="{$flag}"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your first paragraph makes perfect sense, thanks for helping me understand where I went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

**The problem is that you are creating two attributes with the same name** -- `Value`. In a wellformed XML document an element cannot have more than one attribute with the same name.

**To quote the [W3C XSLT 2.0 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123/#constructing-complex-content)** (this is exactly the same in XSLT 1.0, too):

> *9. If an attribute A in the result sequence has the same name as another attribute B that appears later in the result sequence, then
>   attribute A is discarded from the result sequence*.

So, whenever XSLT generates for an element more than one attributes with the same name, only the last attribute is copied to the output -- and this is what you see.

**Here is a short and simple solution (only two templates, no conditionals, no parameters)**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vDoc" select="/"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vMatch" select=
 "('Affirmative', 'Negative')[2 - number($vDoc/*/*/HEAD/FLAG eq 'Yes')]"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <Interface>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*/BODY/RECORD"/>
  </Interface>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="RECORD">
  <Data Match="{$vMatch}" Value="{Value}"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<ENVELOPE>
    <PRODUCT>
        <HEAD>
            <FLAG>No</FLAG>
        </HEAD>
        <BODY>
            <RECORD>
                <Value>9</Value>
            </RECORD>
            <RECORD>
                <Value>10</Value>
            </RECORD>
            <MISC>9</MISC>
        </BODY>
    </PRODUCT>
</ENVELOPE>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<Interface>
   <Data Match="Negative" Value="9"/>
   <Data Match="Negative" Value="10"/>
</Interface>
```

Comment: Thank you Dimitre. I've learnt so much looking at your answers on StackOverflow, the array/variable construct looks powerful.